# Git- Is it a good practice to create a pull request for the new code in new repo?

Tags: git

Today i pushed my code to a newly created repo. But i was thinking if it is a good practice to create a pull request to push this new code? As there will be huge amount of files ,it will become difficult for reviewer to review these many files.
Which one will be a good practice?

Comment: Yes it is good practise before you push your code.

Comment: Creating a PR and make it approve by the reviewer is the good practice, Thanks

Comment: In my experience you should push multiple commits with good commit messages and then create a pull request. Reviewer sees every commit and knows according to commit message what have you done.